# OpenGL JOGL texture outline

Tags: java, opengl, textures, jogl

I'm drawing some points in OpenGL (JOGL) as follows:

```
BufferedImage image = loadMyTextureImage();
Texture tex = TextureIO.newTexture(image, false);
tex.setTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
tex.setTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
tex.bind();

gl.glColor4f(r,g,b,a);        
gl.glBegin(GL_POINTS);
for ( int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++ ) {
   // compute x,y,z
   gl.glVertex3f(x,y,z);
}
gl.glEnd();
```

My `image` is a white image, so I can reuse that same texture and just color it using `gl.glColor4f`, but I would like to draw an outline around it in a different color. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You don't need a texture at all if it is just pure white :-) Also what sort of outline do you want? Thin coloured line of arbitrary colour? "glow" around edges? gradient fill to edges? It depends a lot on what sort of artistic effect you are trying to achieve...

Comment: I am using a texture to vary the shape of the point. This seems to be significantly faster because I can still use GL_POINTS rather than creating a polygon with that shape. For the outline, I'm just trying to get a thin line of arbitrary color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the texture to determine the shape of the point, then the obvious way to do the outline would be to add a second texture to draw the outline of the point on top.

The outline texture would also be white, so you could colour it to any colour you like in the same way.

Depending on the alpha-blending mode you use, this can also be used to give a "glowing" edge effect.

Comment: I thought about doing it that way, but I think that would require me to draw all of the outlines first and then all of the fills (or vice versa) since I don't think I can switch textures while I'm in GL_POINTS. This would lead to all of the fills to be on top of all of the outlines.

Comment: You can bind two textures at once (though you might need GLSL to get certain blending effects). This is probably the best approach for performance reasons anyway.